# Triple integral over a pyramid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to calculate the integral $\iiint_D (1-z^2)dxdydz$ where $D$ is the pyramid with vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(1,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$.

Is the pyramid the following?

[image]

Can only $C$ be the top of the pyramid?

How can we find the limits of $x,y,z$ that we have to use an the integrals?

Answer (score 2):

The equation of plane $ADC$ is $x+z=1$.

The equation of plane $BDC$ is $y+z=1$.

$$\iiint_D (1-z^2)dxdydz= \int_0^1\int_0^x\int_0^{1-x}(1-z^2)\,dz\,dy\,dx+\int_0^1\int_x^1\int_0^{1-y}(1-z^2)\,dz\,dy\,dx$$

Comment: So, the pyramid is the space between the planes $ADC$ and $BDC$, right? So, is the space $D$ the set $\{(x,y,z) \mid x+z=1, 0\leq y \leq 1 \ \text{ and } \ y+z=1 , 0\leq x\leq 1\}$ ?

Comment: I think $\{(x,y,z) \mid 0\leq x+z\leq1, 0\leq y \leq 1 \ \text{ and } \ 0\leq y+z\leq1 , 0\leq x\leq 1\}$

Comment: So, we have that $$\{(x,y,z) \mid 0\leq x+z\leq1, 0\leq y \leq 1 \ \text{ and } \ 0\leq y+z\leq1 , 0\leq x\leq 1\} \\ =\{(x,y,z) \mid 0\leq x+z\leq1, 0\leq y \leq 1\}\cup\{(x,y,z) \mid 0\leq y+z\leq1 , 0\leq x\leq 1\} \\ :=D_1\cup D_2$$ At $D_1$ we have that $0\leq y\leq 1$ and $0\leq x+z\leq 1 \Rightarrow -x\leq z\leq 1-x$. Since $z\geq 0$ we get $0\leq z\leq 1-x$. It must hold that $1-x\geq 0 \Rightarrow x\leq 1$ and since $x\geq 0$ we get $0\leq x\leq 1$.

Comment: Therefore, $D_1=\{(x, y, z)\mid 0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 1, 0\leq z\leq 1-x\}$. And in the same way we get $D_1=\{(x, y, z)\mid 0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 1, 0\leq z\leq 1-y\}$. And so we get $$\iiint_D (1-z^2)dxdydz= \int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}(1-z^2)dzdydx+\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^{1-y}(1-z^2)dzdydx$$ You have different boundaries at the integrals, why?

Comment: Why don't you observe geometrically?

Comment: As picture shows, $0<x<1$. Intersection two planes is plane $y=x$ which contact plane $z=0$ in line $y=x$. this determine $y<x$ and $y>x$ separately!

Comment: Do you mean the following? We have the planes ADC and BDC. At the plane $z=0$ the point C coincides with point E. Then we have ADE and BDE. These two triangles intersect at y=x.

Comment: Think about projection plane $y=x$ on horizontal plane $z=0$.

Comment: I got stuck right now... Which plane do we project on z=0?

Comment: The plane $y=x$ is different from line $y=x$ on $z=0$. If my comments make you confused, I can finish.

Comment: So, the planes $x+z=1$ and $y+z=1$ intersect at the plane $y=x$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$, right?

Comment: In whole $R^3$ specially $0<x<1$.